# locating city that serves the most other cities within a given radius

Tags: python, algorithm

this is essentially what I need to solve:

> You are given a radius of coverage `r` (in miles) and asked to locate the fewest number of facilities, with each facility being located at one of the 128 cities in the data set, so that every one of the 128 cities in the data set is within `r` miles from some facility

```
data=[Cities, Population, Coordinates, Distances]
```

for this problem I am only concerned with the Cities and Distances sublists from data (above)
the Cities list contains 128 cities
the Distances list contains 128 sublists containing the 128 distances from itself and the other cities

for example lets say

```
Cities= [cityA, cityB, cityC, cityD]
```

then

```
Distances= [[0,25,50,75],[25,0,30,40], [50,30,0,45], [75,40,45,0]]
```

(these distances are completely made up)
so in each sublist in the Distances list, the distance corresponds with the index of the city in the Cities list, so the first distance in the sublist is always the distance from that city to the first city (cityA) and the second distance is the distance from that city to the second city (cityB)

I already have a helper function that looks like this:

```
def nearbyCities(name, r, data) :
''' Returns a list of cities within distance r of named city
    sorted in alphabetical order.
    Returns an empty list if city name is invalid. '''

cities = data[0]
distances = data[3]

result = []
if name in cities :                # If the city name is valid
    i = cities.index(name)           # Get the index of the named city
    for j in range(len(cities)) :      # For every other city
        if distances[i][j] <= r :      # If within r of named city
            result = result + [cities[j]]  # Add to result
result.sort() 
return result
```

I need to write a function called `def locateFacilities(data, r)`.
The list of cities returned by this function should be in alphabetical order.
This function should implement the greedy algorithm described:

> Greedy Algorithm for facility location:
>
> 1. Initially all cities are unserved
> 2. while there are cities that are unserved:  pick a city `c` that serves the most unserved cities  mark city `c` and all cities within
>      `r` miles of `c` as served
>
> Within the function `locateFacilities`, you might want to use an
>   additional data structure called served that keep tracks of which
>   cities have already been served by the facilities located thus far.
>   The served data structure could simply be a boolean list of length
>   128, initialized to all `False` values. The element in position `i` in
>   this list indicates whether city `i` (i.e., the city in position `i`
>   in the list cities) has been served or not. Once such a data structure
>   has been defined, you can then find out for any given city `c` the
>   number of cities, not yet served, that are within radius `r` of `c`
>   (you should write a function for this!). If you implement this, the
>   greedy algorithm repeatedly locates a facility at a city `c` for which
>   the number of “unserved” cites within radius `r` of `c` is maximum.
>
> I can figure this out in my head in english with what I need to do but
>   am really struggling with figuring out how to put it into code

Comment: Could you post (or link) some sample data?

Comment: This is similar to (but not the same as) cluster analysis. There are some decent heuristic algorithms out there to solve these types of problems. A naive solution will take a long amount of time to find the optimal solution.

Comment: @IceArdor While this is true, OP's assignment defines the algorithm (useless as it may be) to be used.

Comment: Sounds a lot like **minimum set cover problem** to me. Each facility covers a set of cities, and you are looking for the minimum number of facilities needed to cover all cities, right?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse As I read it, he is not looking for the minimum solution, but for the solution given by the algorithm specified in the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact data structure it is a bit hard. Hence the `getDistance` function in the following snippet is magical.

The following code has not been tested as I don't have data, but maybe it can give you some ideas:

```
def getDistance (city1, city2):
    #magic happens here
    #maybe return data [3] [city1.dix] [city2.idx]
    return #the distance between cities

class City:
    def __init__ (self, idx, name):
        self.idx = idx
        self.name = name

    def makeNeighbours (self, cities, radius):
        self.neighbours = [city for city in cities
            if city is not self and getDistance (self, city) <= r]

    def removeNeighbour (self, city):
        if city not in self.neighbours: return
        self.neighbours.remove (city)

    def __eq__ (self, other):
        return self.idx == other.idx


def locateFacilities (cities, radius):
    cities = [City (idx, name) for idx, name in enumerate (data [0] ) ]
    for city in cities: city.makeNeighbours (cities, radius)
    facilities = []
    while cities:
        mostNeighbours = sorted (cities, key = lambda c: -len (c.neighbours) ) [0]
        for city in cities:
            city.removeNeighbour (mostNeighbours)
        for city in mostNeighbours.neighbours:
            cities.remove (city)
        cities.remove (mostNeighbours)
        facilities.append (mostNeighbours)
    print ('Place facilities at:')
    for facility in facilities:
        print (facility.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the problem description you can already write a part of the `locateFacilities` function without to much hard thinking (of course there are different ways to code this but let's stick to the data structure recommended in the assignment):

```
def locateFacilities(data, r):
    n = len(data[0])

    served = [False] * n
    facilities = []
    while not all(served):
        # 1. Find city with most unserved neighbors
        # 2. Place a facility in this city, i.e.:
        #   - Mark city and neighbors as served
        #   - Put city name in list of facilities
        # 3. Repeat

    facilities.sort()
    return facilities
```

You already know how to do a part of the code enclosed in the while loop, but I think you're going to find it easier to work with the cities' indices instead of the names.